# In which episode does Luffy get his finger stuck in a bottle?

Tags: one-piece

Does anyone know in which episode Zoro cuts a bottle that Luffy has his finger stuck in with an axe?

Here is a picture showing the scene:

[image: Pictures of Zoro chopping the bottle Luffy has his finger stuck in]

Comment: @Angelplayer: My understanding is that questions about when something occurred in a series (provided that the series is already known) are still acceptable; it's identifying _works_ that's more or less off-topic now.

Comment: I can't confirm this because I am at work right now, but I believe this is happened in one of the earliest OVA's

Comment: @Angelplayer Maroon is right; if it's within a known series, it's not considered an identification request. There's no reason to close this. I still think this is a lousy question, though, and voted accordingly.

Comment: @Maroon I stand corrected. Thank you for clearing that up!

Answer (score 2):

This comes from a special that aired after episode 53, [One Piece: Adventure in the Ocean's Navel.](http://myanimelist.net/anime/1094/One_Piece__Umi_no_Heso_no_Daibouken-hen?q=ocean%27s%20navel)

Comment: cudos to you for actually knowing that. I see these questions come up often here and have the hardest time finding episode numbers. The most I can do is pin it to an arc :-(